# How to store form data in form pagination using session?

Tags: django, session, pagination, django-sessions

I'm working on a quiz. The quiz has multiple questions - forms. Since there may be many questions, I've created a pagination for these forms. Everything seems to work correctly but only the data from forms on last page are sent to server.

How to hold the data from previous pages so I can send all forms then to server?

I'm considering using session but can't figure out how to make it work. As you can see, all questions are in one form  with method post. But pagination are GET methods.

```
def take_quiz(request,id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        quiz = get_object_or_404(models.LanguageQuiz, pk=id)
        sitting = get_object_or_404(models.Sitting, quiz=quiz, user=request.user)
        for k,v in request.POST.iteritems():
            if 'choice-for' in k:
                q = Question.objects.get(pk=k.split('-')[-1])
                choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=v)
                sitting_question = get_object_or_404(SittingQuestion,sitting=sitting,question=q)
                sitting_question.answer = choice
                sitting_question.save()
        correct_answers = len([x for x in sitting.sitting_questions.all() if x.answer.correct])
        result = float(correct_answers)/sitting.sitting_questions.all().count() * 100

        return render(request,'quiz/result.html',context={'result':result,
                                                          'level':level,
                                                          'quiz':quiz})

    if request.method == 'GET':

        with transaction.atomic():
            quiz = get_object_or_404(models.LanguageQuiz, pk=id)

            if models.Sitting.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, user=request.user).exists():
                sitting = get_object_or_404(models.Sitting, quiz=quiz, user=request.user)
                check_expired_sitting(sitting)
                sitting.delete()

            sitting = models.Sitting.objects.create(quiz=quiz, user=request.user)
            sitting.load_questions()

        questions = [x.question for x in sitting.sitting_questions.all()]
        paginator = Paginator(questions,2)
        page_num = request.GET.get('page',1)
        page = paginator.page(page_num)

        context = {'page':page,
                   'quiz':quiz}

        return render(request,'quiz/quiz.html',context=context)
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ quiz.name }}</h1>
    <br><br><br>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% for question in page.object_list %}
            <div class="question">
                <h3>{{ question.text }}</h3>
                <div class="choices">
                    {% for choice in question.get_choices_list %}
                        <input type="radio" name="choice-for-question-{{ question.id }}"
                               id="choice-{{ question.id }}-{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
                        <label for="choice-{{ question.id }}-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.text }}</label><br/>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% if not page.has_next %}
        <button class='accordion' type="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
    <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can also think of only two possible solutions.
One is the inefficient one in which every time a page is changed, you submit the values (answers) of the questions on the current page and then they'll be updated in the DB with a flag(boolean field) associated to them which will be false until the final submit button is pressed to submit all answers across all pages.
But this is very inefficient & costly.
Other method is how you are trying to do it, using sessions. And for this you can bring in REDIS into play and store the question & answer key value pairs in it for that session.